# Why is docker-in-docker using so much disk space?

Tags: docker

I often run a VS Code devcontainer for developing a Home Assistant add-on.  This devcontainer runs Docker (inside of my host Docker).  After a few hours of working, my host Docker runs out of disk space which causes various problems.  Here it shows that this dev container is using 52GB which I believe is excessive.

```
% docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          1         1         1.333GB   0B (0%)
Containers      1         1         52.17GB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   1         1         220.2MB   0B (0%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

Inside the dev container, `df` shows that most of this usage comes from Docker VFS:

```
% docker exec 7f666319eddf du -hd 1 /var/lib/docker/       
54G /var/lib/docker/vfs
448K    /var/lib/docker/containerd
8.0K    /var/lib/docker/tmp
20M /var/lib/docker/image
28K /var/lib/docker/volumes
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/swarm
3.1M    /var/lib/docker/containers
116K    /var/lib/docker/buildkit
16K /var/lib/docker/plugins
4.0K    /var/lib/docker/runtimes
88K /var/lib/docker/network
54G /var/lib/docker/
```

But inside the container, docker thinks its containers are using less than 1GB.

```
$ docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          21        19        2.829GB   714.7MB (25%)
Containers      100       8         628.7MB   605.8MB (96%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

And yet, after running `docker container prune` that 54GB shrinks to 28GB.  So why doesn't this usage appear in `docker system df` ?

I'm running Docker Desktop 4.28.0 on macOS Sonoma.  I also have the same problem on Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

This frequently happens when `/var/lib/docker` is inside the container and not a volume. The container filesystem will often be overlay, and it's not possible to define an overlay filesystem inside of an overlay filesystem.

The fallback when a layered filesystem driver is not available is to use the "native" or "vfs" driver, which is just a copy of the entire filesystem for each layer. So if you have a 100MB image, and add a single 1MB file in the docker image, you now have 201MB of storage on the drive, 100MB for the original layer, and 101MB for the new layer. Every container also needs to add a read/write layer on the filesystem, so the entire image gets copied for every created container.

The fix is to mount a volume for `/var/lib/docker` and make sure the source for that mount is [a supported backing filesystem](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/#supported-backing-filesystems) by one of the layered filesystem drivers.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try this. Do you know of some diagnostic tool in Docker that would show the accurate usage?

Comment: @ElliottB If that is the cause, I'd follow up in the issues on github.com/moby/moby to fix the df output for that graph driver.